# Send To | Mail Recipient always sends the email in plain text

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, html, plaintext

Whenever you select to send a file by email (right click on it and select Send To | Mail recipient) the email is automatically in plain text and additional text is included:

> Your message is ready to be sent with the following file or link
>   attachments: call log.csv
>
> Note: To
>   protect against computer viruses,
>   e-mail programs may prevent sending or
>   receiving certain types of file
>   attachments.  Check your e-mail
>   security settings to determine how
>   attachments are handled.

How can I send the email in HTML automatically and how can I remove the additional text from the email body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work for me, unless you add `/a` after the "ipm.note"... then it works (Outlook 2007).

Still, there is a much better solution (VBS script) that allows multiple attachments and signatures at [Stephen's Scribble Pad](https://web.archive.org/web/20111225041903/http://smmeyer.com/scribble/?p=48).

Comment: For me it worked without adding "/a"
Thanks for the link, the script is excellent. I will mark this answer as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Although it can be done, it does look a little bit complicated. See ["Outlook: Send To Mail Recipient opens an Outlook plain text message"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234487) from Microsoft:

> The methods described use the simple Messaging Application Programming Interface (MAPI) function MAPISendMail(), which does not use the Outlook default message format. This function always creates a plain text formatted message.

### The solution

> To work around this issue, change the Sendto function to use the Outlook default message format, for example, Rich Text Format (RTF) or Hypertext Markup Language (HTML). (To set the Outlook default message format, click Options on the Tools menu, click Mail Format, and in the Send in this message format list, click the format that you want to use.)
>
> To change the Sendto function to use the Outlook default message format, you need to create a shortcut in the Send To folder that calls an Outlook formatted message window:
>
> 1. In Microsoft Windows Explorer, double-click to open the Windows\SendTo folder. 
>      Note If you are using Windows XP, or later, the \SendTo folder is located in the following path: %userprofile%\SendTo
> 2. Right-click the background of the Contents pane (the large pane on the right), point to New on the shortcut menu, and then click Shortcut.
> 3. Type the path to the Outlook.exe file, or click Browse and to browse to the Outlook.exe file.
> 4. Type a space followed by /c ipm.note following the last character on the command line, for example:
>      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Outlook.exe" /c ipm.note
>      Note that the /c switch is outside the command line quotation marks.
> 5. Click Next.
> 6. Type Mail Recipient Using Outlook in the Select a name for the shortcut box, and then click Finish.
>
> To test to see if the Sendto function uses the Outlook default message format, right-click a file on the Windows desktop, point to Send To on the shortcut menu, and then click Mail Recipient Using Outlook. An Outlook e-mail form should open that contains only the file as an attachment.

Comment: Thanks, that works just great!

Josh can you please add in your answer the full path for Vista, it might not be very easy for other users to find it. In my case is:
C:\Users\Nicu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows

Answer (score 0):

Too bad it doesen't work for multiple attached items though... It only attaches one file from the group.